# Assignment expression scoping in list comprehension problem

Tags: python, python-3.8

I ran into a problem when trying to solve a problem I saw on stackoverflow. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63445775/simple-conditional-statement-not-operating-as-expected)

Here's my code:

```
def fizz_buzz(n):
    return ['fizzbuzz' if (f:=i%2==0) and (b:=i%5==0) else 'fizz' if f else 'buzz' if b else i for i in range(n)]
print(fizz_buzz(70))
```

The above code works perfectly but when I try to add a start value to the `range()` function I get an error the free variable 'b' referenced before assignment.

I don't understand why this is happening

Comment: not sure if it's pythonic way to write a function. Pep20 states: "Simple is better than complex." and "Readability counts." So, why don't you make it simpler?

Comment: I'm just trying things and I got this!  I wanna know WHY!  That's how to learn I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User user2357112 is right.

> Your condition:
>
> ```py
> (f:=i%2==0) and (b:=i%5==0)
> ```
>
> only assigns b if `f` is `True`, but you try to use b anyway.

I want to add some explanation about that.

It is OK when you start from `0` because the `f` is `True` at first (`0%2==0`), so `b` is computed for the next iterations in the forloop; But if you start from `1`, it is not.

For example if you try with `range(2, n)`, it works fine.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I understand that the problem has to do with Short circuit evaluation

Answer (score 2):

Your condition:

```
(f:=i%2==0) and (b:=i%5==0)
```

only assigns `b` if `f` is true, but you try to use `b` anyway.